# LINQ - Iterate over a collection of dates and perform a calculation

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datetime, lambda

I have a collection of an object with a DateTime and an decimal property. All dates in the collection are unique and sorted to be sequential.

```
public class RateChange
{
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming the first rate change is the start date and the end date is the current DateTime.UtcNow. How can i iterate over this collection and multiply the Rate * Days between each date and then sum the total of these results using LINQ only.

Comment: No it is not homework. I know how to work out the days between two dates and multiply by a number ! My problem is I dont know how to express this using only LINQ over my collection. To be more specific its for a result transformer that transforms the results of an database index, which runs on RavenDB server. These transformers must be coded using LINQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this...

```
rateChanges
    .Zip(rateChanges
           .Skip(1)
           .Concat(new[]{
              new RateChange{
                    EffectiveDate = DateTime.Now.Date,
                    Rate = 0M //we never use this
              }
           }),
         (r1, r2) => r1.Rate * (r2 - r1).TotalDays)
    .Sum();
```

Due to the double iteration of rateChanges, it's probably best to ensure it's a materialized collection such as array or `List<RateChange>`